# Ava js not working async await tests

Tags: ava

I am trying to use Ava.js for my tests but actually I can't launch async/await. I just copy/paste an example from documentation and it showed to me an error.

```
(async function(t) {
SyntaxError: missing) after argument list.
```

looks like it not compiled correctly and I don't know what I did wrong. Could someone help me please?

Here is my code

**test.spec.js**

```
import test from 'ava';

test(async t => {
    const value = await promiseFn();
    t.true(value);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ava"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^0.16.0",
    "ava-spec": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "tap-nyan": "0.0.2"
  },
  "ava": {
    "babel": "inherit",
    "require": [
      "babel-register"
    ]
  }
}
```

and **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async/await` are not transpiled using the preset `es2015`.
You should enable the preset `es2017` or [`latest`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest/).

Another solution is to run your test suite on Node v7 since it natively support `async/await`.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. Shame on me :)   Thank you so much Florent.